# Recursively diff certain types of files in directories

Tags: linux, unix

I was trying to find a method that I can use on the linux/unix/mac command line to find the difference between two directories but limited to certain file types.

For example, I want to find the differences between dir1 and dir2 but limit the file types to .java.  
 Ex: `diff dir1/**.java dir2/**.java`  this should give me diff between dir1/Test.java and dir2/Test.java and also dir1/Test2.java dir2/Test2.java, etc.

I am somewhat familiar with the "diff" command on linux.  But you may mention any other commands that can be used to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

Start with `diff -qr dir1 dir2` and constinue with what you want.
Or use something like `git` for source control and use `git status` or `git diff`.